# Azure Python SDK: How to set auto-shutdown task on VMs?

Tags: python, azure, shutdown

On Azure Portal I can set auto-shutdown for a VM but can't find the API command for the Python SDK anywhere. Is this possible at the moment? Do I have to use DevTestLab? The SDK in question: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python

Answer (score -1):

1.The `auto-shutdown` in the portal is configured as part of the VM's deployment template. If you updated the template, you could certainly deploy it in whatever way you choose.

2.You could schedule a script using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/poweroff) in Azure to start/stop the VM at any schedule of your choosing. The script could deployed on [Webjobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs), [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) or [Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/).

Comment: Thanks for the input Jay. Yes I'm using template at the moment but for our use case we need an API. We're building a web portal to allow users to stop/start their own VM. We want to set a run-time in case they forget to deallocate the VM.  REST API works but it would be nice to have it in the SDK as well for completion. I guess I should take it up with the devs at Github.  Anyway, I've found a solution thats' satisfactory:  because we're using Django, I've loaded Celery to schedule the shutdown task. Celery is more flexible because we may want to schedule startup and shutdowns in the future.